# Can I require a "sign-off" checkbox to be checked before a merge can be done?

Tags: github, pull-request

In my current team, in one project we need to do a manual step before every merge. I would like to have a checkbox which I need to click which says something like "I ran the integration test XY". If that checkbox is not clicked, one cannot merge.

Is it possible to add such a checkbox in Github? Maybe via a [status check](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/collaborating-on-repositories-with-code-quality-features/about-status-checks)? Maybe a TODO list could be added to every PR automatically and block the PR from being merged before everything is checked?

Answer (score 5):

you can add checkboxes in our pull requets via markdown:

```markdown
### Checklist
- [ ] I have performed a self-review of my code.
- [ ] PR can be merged by a reviewer.
```

this will render as a movable and clickable checkbox list, that will update your description on check. so it will persist.

you can also create a pull request template that includes this checklist, if you need it for all PRs. to do that create a file `.github/pull_request_template.md` with the contents of your template

read more on the [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository), [about task lists](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/about-task-lists)

then use **github actions** to check for these tasklists:
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/task-completed-checker

Answer (score -2):

@alex's solution is a good one but configuring Github checklists via Github actions can be a pain and suck up a lot of time since the debug workflow is very slow to give you feedback.

There are more user-friendly alternatives. There are some tools in the GitHub marketplace designed to address this kind of problem directly. One of them is, [Pull Checklist](https://www.pullchecklist.com/), I actually made it so I'm a bit biased. This tool and others like Pull Request Checklist Buddy can help you put together blocking checklists with conditions depending on the files you change among other parameters. They might be worth a look if you want to sidestep some of the annoyances of GitHub Actions.